# How to validate Json Web Token (JWT) via Java-Jwt API?

Tags: jwt

I am new to oauth and JSON Web Token (jwt). I am trying to validate an authorization token (jwt) via Java JWT api (https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt). I was able to decode the header and payload via that API but having trouble to validate the token.

Little I know of this area, I thought I had to add jwks-rs-java api (https://github.com/auth0/jwks-rsa-java)  to my test project in order to handle validation part so I imported and ran following statements based on the documentation I read.

The "oauth_server_domain" is Oracle Access Manager (oam).

```
JwkProvider provider = new UrlJwkProvider("oauth_server_domain");
Jwk jwk = provider.get("keyId_name");
```

Then I got following exceptions:

```
com.auth0.jwk.SigningKeyNotFoundException: Cannot obtain jwks from url https://<oauth_server_domain>/.well-known/jwks.json 
Caused by javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I am trying to understand the problem itself and how to rectify it.

- Did I provide wrong key id?
- Do I need to import a certificate of the remote "oauth_server_domain" into my local box in where I build/execute project in IDE?
- How to add ./well-known/jwks.json into oauth server (e.g. OAM)?

Update:

I do have a certificate (in *.der format) with a public key from the authorization server (oam). It seems like I need to manually create ./well-known/jwks.json file by following this guide (https://auth0.com/blog/navigating-rs256-and-jwks/). I think I should be able to convert binary encoded cert to base64 based cert (*.pem format?).

But how can I expose that relative path from authorization server (e.g. https://auth_server_domain:port/.well-known/jwks.json)?

I'd appreciate your advice and input on this matter. Thank you!